# Is there any method in dbutils to check existence of a file, something like dbutils.fs.exits?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I wish to check if at certain location, say **/dbfs/FileStore/tables/xyz.json** exists or not. If yes, then the method should return true. I checked method in dbutils but doesn't seem to find any. Plus, I cannot mount any location in ADLS. What are the ways and how can I workaround with it ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to check is by using dbutils.fs.ls.

Say, for your example.

```
check_path = 'FileStore/tables/'
check_name = 'xyz.json'

files_list = dbutils.fs.ls(check_path)
files_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(files_list)
result = files_sdf.filter(col('name') == check_name)
```

Then you can use .count(), or .show(), to get what you want.

For the second question, can you elaborate what you meant by cannot mount?

Comment: user wanted to know the solution using DButils only, which is specific to DBFS.